# How do I get to this answer without have to solve for a 4th degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

[image]

This is question regarding solving for a percentile of the cumulative distribution function of a certain pdf. What I am wondering is how I am meant to get to this answer without having to solve a complex polynomial. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: There's only one instance of $\pi_{0.75}$ in the equation, and yoi can easily undo each part step-by-step...

Comment: So if you take 1 over to the other side you have -0.25, which then needs to be square rooted, but you can't square root a negative ?

Comment: Why are you trying to square root without removing the negatives from both sides then?

Comment: Oh that is true, I completely missed that minus sign. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{3}{4} &= 1 - \left[1-\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2 +\frac{4}{60} \right]^2  \\
\dfrac{-1}{4} &= - \left[1-\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2 +\frac{4}{60} \right]^2  \\
\dfrac{1}{4} &= \left[1-\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2 +\frac{4}{60} \right]^2  \\
\pm \dfrac{1}{2} &= 1-\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2 +\frac{4}{60}   \\
\pm \dfrac{30}{60} - \dfrac{60}{60} - \frac{4}{60} &= -\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2   \\
\dfrac{\{-34,-94\}}{60} &= -\dfrac{1}{60}(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2   \\
\{34,94\} &= (\pi_{0.75}+6)^2   \\
\{\pm\sqrt{34},\pm\sqrt{94}\} &= \pi_{0.75}+6  \\
\{\pm\sqrt{34} - 6,\pm\sqrt{94} - 6\} &= \pi_{0.75}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where we have used the somewhat nonstandard notation "$\text{set} = \text{expression}$" ro represent that the expression can take any value in the set.

This gives all four roots of your polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $(\pi_{0.75}+6)^2=x$ and solve for $x$
$$\frac 3 4=1-\left(1-\frac x {60} +\frac 4 {60}\right)^2$$ that is to say
$$\frac 1 4=\left(\frac{16}{15}-\frac{x}{60}\right)^2$$ which gives as solutions $x=34$ and $x=94$.

This is not too complex.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it.